# antlr4 - not getting function correctly

Tags: antlr, antlr4

```
grammar Expr;

// parser rules
prog : ((decl_list expr_seq | expr_seq) ';' NEWLINE?)*;

decl_list : decl (decl)*;

expr_seq : expr (expr)*;

decl : DEF fun var_list '=' expr ENDEF
     | DEF fun '=' expr ENDEF
     ;

var_list : param (param)*;

expr_list : expr ',' expr;

expr : LET var '=' expr IN expr         # assignExpr
     | fun CALL                         # callExpr
     | fun '(' expr_list ')'            # callExpr
     | expr ('*'|'/') expr              # infixExpr
     | expr ('+'|'-') expr              # infixExpr 
     | '(' expr ')'                     # parensExpr
     | num                              # numberExpr
     | '~' expr                         # negateExpr
     | var                              # varExpr
     ;

num  : '-'? INT
     | '-'? FLOAT
     ;

fun  : STR (('0' | '1' | '2' | '3' | '4' | '5' | '6' | '7' | '8' | '9')* STR)*;

var  : STR (('_' | '-') STR)*;

param : STR ('_' STR)*;

// lexer rules                    
NEWLINE: [\r\n]+ ;
INT: [0-9]+ ;          // should handle negatives
FLOAT: [0-9]+'.'[0-9]* ; // should handle signs(+/-)
WS: [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
DEF: 'def';
ENDEF: 'endef';
LET: 'let';
IN: 'in';
CALL: '()';
STR: [a-zA-Z]+;
```

i am making f1vae interpreter with antlr4. above is my current parser and lexer grammer. it starts from prog.

when i put this as input:

```
g(1,x);
```

it parses like this:

```
(prog (expr_seq (expr (var g)) (expr ( (expr 1 ,) x ))) ; \n)
```

the parser seems to think g as a variable, even if the "fun '(' expr_list ')" is in the higher priority. why is this happening?

Comment: This _is_ the same as in your various other questions: `('0' | '1' | '2' | '3' | '4' | '5' | '6' | '7' | '8' | '9')` are overlapping with the `INT` rule. Replace `fun  : STR (('0' | '1' | '2' | '3' | '4' | '5' | '6' | '7' | '8' | '9')* STR)*;` with `fun  : STR (INT? STR)*;`

Comment: Also note that you are "gluing" identifier characters together in the parsers (and you're skipping spaces in the lexer!), input like `g h j` _will_ be matched as a `fun` (after all, those are multiple `STR` tokens). I don't thing that is what you want.